# Rails - Migrate error when change the database info to environment variables - AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04

I have 2 servers.

1. Amazon EC2 - The real production server. This is the app's live version
2. Heroku - This is my "test" production server. Some actions are made in production server, then, to test before send to AWS EC2, I test in Heroku.

In the file `config/database.yml`, I have the following code:

```
production:
    adapter: <%= ENV['DB_ADAPTER'] ||= 'postgresql' %>
    encoding: utf8
    pool: 5
    host: 127.0.0.1
    username: my_pg_username
    password: my_pg_password
    database: my_pg_database
```

It works fine in AWS, but the connection data in Heroku is different.

To solve this, I create some environment variables in both servers.

In Heroku, is very easier. I go to App Settings and in the Config Vars, I set the name and the value.

In AWS, I:

1. Log via SSH
2. Run `sudo nano .profile` to edit the file `.profile`
3. Add the code

   ```
   export PG_DB_HOST='127.0.0.1'
   export PG_DB_USER='my_pg_user'
   export PG_DB_PASS='my_pg_password'
   export PG_DB_NAME='my_pg_database'
   ```
4. After that, I run these same codes in terminal. With this, the environment variables persists.

To test if the environment variables is working, I log in the server and log in the `rails console`, after that, I type the variable, and returns the value correctly.

In the file `config/database.yml`, I changed the code:

```
production:
    adapter: <%= ENV['DB_ADAPTER'] ||= 'postgresql' %>
    encoding: utf8
    pool: 5
    host: <%= ENV['PG_DB_HOST'] %>
    username: <%= ENV['PG_DB_USER'] %>
    password: <%= ENV['PG_DB_PASS'] %>
    database: <%= ENV['PG_DB_NAME'] %>
```

In Heroku, after the deploy, works fine.

In AWS, I got an error when run `cap production deploy`. In the task `rake db:migrate`, I got this error:

```
    01 bundle install --path /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@XX.XX.XX.XXX 4.514s
00:27 deploy:migrate
    [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
00:28 deploy:migrating
    01 bundle exec rake db:migrate
    01 DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to c…
    01
    01 rake aborted!
    01
    01 ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
    01
    01 /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter…
    01
    01 /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter…
    01
    01 /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter…
    01
    01 /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter…
    01
    01 /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter…
    01
    01 /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio…
    01
    01 /home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conn
```

If I return to the old values, works. With env variables, breaks.

**Environment**

```
ruby -v: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v: Rails 4.2.3
pg_config --version: PostgreSQL 9.3.8
psql --version: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.8
bundle -v: Bundler version 1.13.7
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
```

I appreciatte any help. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Somar--

You might try switching to the ENV variables one at a time. First update `config/database.yml` to use `ENV['PG_DB_HOST']`, leaving the other values hard-coded. Try to deploy and see if you receive the error. If not, continue adding the remaining ENV variables until the deploy fails.

This might help you determine if a specific ENV variable is causing the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Jeremy! Thanks your answer! After did what you say, the problem works. I think this is not the correct way to create environment variables in AWS EC2...